# is Tradingview backtesting able to short on open price of the candle?

Tags: pine-script

I'm so confused with the tradingview's backtesting. I saw that when it entered long entry, it entered at open price of the candle. But when it shorted, it shorted at close price of the candle.

Is it possible to config that? I cannot find anywhere.

```
strategy.entry("LONG ENTRY", strategy.long, when = buysignals)
strategy.entry("SHORT ENTRY", strategy.short, when = sellsignals)
```

Here's the screenshot of what I saw.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your short entry there is entering at the open, as does the long entry, which corresponds to expected behavior, unless you use `process_orders_on_close=true` in your [`strategy()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy) call.